# Hyper-V R2 Performance Counters

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, hyper-v

I've been playing around with the WMI performance counters for Hyper-V. Of interest to me are the Virtual NIC bytes/sec input and output counters. I notice that the results are very "spikey". Over what time period is the latest counter averaged? I'm trying to calculate total traffic volume per VM, but sometimes a very high instantaneous poll result is inflating the result as I only poll the result each minute.

I would prefer to read a 'bytes total' counter instead of a 'bytes/sec' counter - is there such a thing?

Thanks

Acendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest counter is not averaged at all. It is simply the difference between current and last recoded value. So, spiky behavior (normal for most servers under small load) ishows spiky.

bytes total - not sure you would really prefer them. Think this through - it wold give you an always going up value that is meaningless AND that does definitely overflow sooner or later. How long you want the counter to be to survive- 30, 50, 100 days under heavy load?